# Creating an continous increasing list using promise-pool and puppeteer

Tags: javascript, promise, puppeteer

I need to create scraping tool using puppeteer however I have some issues adding items to the queue

What I got

```
const PromisePool = require("@supercharge/promise-pool");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const domain = process.argv[2];

let list = [];
list[0] = domain;

const run = async () => {
  const { results, errors } = await PromisePool.for(list)
    .withConcurrency(2)
    .process(async (webpage) => {
      links = [];

      const getData = async () => {
        return await page.evaluate(async () => {
          return await new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")).map((anchor) => [anchor.href]));
          });
        });
      };

      links = await getData();

      for (var link in links) {
        var new_url = String(links[link]);
        new_url = new_url.split("#")[0];
        console.log("new url: " + new_url);
        if (new_url.includes(domain)) {
          if (new_url in list) {
            console.log("Url already exists: " + new_url);
            continue;
          }

          list[new_url] = new_url;
        } else {
          console.log("Url is external: " + new_url);
        }
      }
      browser.close();
    });
};

const mainFunction = async () => {
  const result = await run();
  return result;
};

(async () => {
  console.log(await mainFunction());
  console.log(list);
})();
```

The problem is inside

```
links = [];

const getData = async () => {
  return await page.evaluate(async () => {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")).map((anchor) => [anchor.href]));
    });
  });
};

links = await getData();
```

page.evaluate is async and it doesn't wait for a return this links is never updated for the next PromisePool process.

I need a way to wait for response to return and then continue rest of the script to process.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`p-queue`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) instead of something that operates on a static list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) to retrieve the same links with a single `await`.

```
page.$$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])
```

It is basically what you are trying to achieve as the `$$eval` method "runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page [context] and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`." [(docs)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args)

E.g.:

```js
const links = await page.$$eval('a', anchors => anchors.map(el => el.href));
```